# How to apply model.fit() function over an CNN-LSTM model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am trying to use this to classify the images into two categories. Also I applied model.fit() function but its showing error.

ValueError: A target array with shape (90, 1) was passed for an output of shape (None, 10) while using as loss binary_crossentropy. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, LSTM
import pickle
import numpy as np

X = np.array(pickle.load(open("X.pickle","rb")))
Y = np.array(pickle.load(open("Y.pickle","rb")))

#scaling our image data
X = X/255.0
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(64 ,(3,3), input_shape = (300,300,1)))

# model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Reshape((16, 16*512)))
model.add(LSTM(128, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(LSTM(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3, decay=1e-5)


model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt,
             metrics=['accuracy'])

# model.summary()
model.fit(X, Y, batch_size=32, epochs = 2, validation_split=0.1)
```

Comment: the shape of your training data `y` have to be equal to the output of your model

Comment: The Y shape is (90,) and dense layer shape is (None,10) so I need to apply Y.reshape(90,10)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is categorical, your issue is that you are using **`binary_crossentropy` instead of `categorical_crossentropy`**; ensure that you do have a categorical instead of a binary classification problem.

Also, please note that if your labels are in simple integer format like [1,2,3,4...] and not one-hot-encoded, your loss_function should be `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`, not `categorical_crossentropy`.

If you do have a binary classification problem, like said in the error of the above ensure that:

1. Loss is binary_crossentroy + `Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')`
2. Loss is categorical_crossentropy + `Dense(2,activation='softmax')`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working fine but how do you get to know that i need to use categorical_crossentropy because my intuition is to use this model for binary classification like distingushing between cats and dogs images. Also is it possible to get confusion matrix from it?

Comment: You need to get the problem definition straight: if you have multiple classes, then it's softmax + categorical/sparse_categorical. You put 10 neurons at the last level... that's how I deduced you have 10 classes not 2. If you do have 1 class as output, ensure that you use binary_crossentropy + sigmoid.

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect to all your possible needs.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is it possible to print confusion matrix for CNN-LSTM model?

Comment: As of TF 2.2, you can use the built-in confusion matrix: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/confusion_matrix.

Comment: Otherwise, you must use the confusion matrix from sklearn: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html

Comment: with model.fit() I am getting more loss than accuracy. Am I doing anything wrong?